# Why is Veda Vyasa Siddhanta different from Vedanta Siddhanta in Sarva Siddhanta Sangraha?

Tags: vedanta, adi-shankaracharya, vyasa, mimamsa

I recently came across the book called [Sarva Siddhanta Sangraha](https://archive.org/details/dli.csl.3538/page/n20/mode/1up) which is claimed to be written by Shri Adi Shankaracharya.

Was this book written by Adi Shankaracharya?

[image: Sarva Siddhanta Sangraha - Contents]

And, in the contents, Veda Vyasa Siddhanta is different from Vedanta Siddhanta. Why is this?

As far as I know, Vedic, Upanishadic, Vedantic, Uttara Mimamsa or Veda Vyasa Siddhanta all point to the same philosophy.

So, why is Veda Vyasa Siddhanta different from Vedanta Siddhanta in Sarva Siddhanta Sangraha?

Comment: I can answer this question if you put this in skeptics stack exchange. (Question can be - Is Shankara the author of sarva siddhanta sangraha?)

Comment: @user23407 but that's not the question, it's more like why does Adi Shankara consider Vyasa Siddhanta different from Vedanta??

Comment: @user23407 or even it's written by a later day scholar, he is well read to write the book, why would he think like that?

Comment: The accepted answer below already addresses this question to a large extent, imo. @MrGreenGold

Comment: @user23407 of no better answer ckmes I'll reward bounty for that. One important point is Advaitins revere Veda Vyasa as thier parama guru. How can they say that his philosophy is different ffrom theirs??

Comment: Shankara does not say anywhere that philosophy of vyAsa is different from advaita.... which leads us to the authorship question. @MrGreenGold

Comment: @user23407 but look at the answer you said is good. It says work is referenced by Vidyaranya and Madhusudana Saraswathi, so the authorship can be attributed to Shankaracharya . Even if it's not Shankaracharya the fact that Madhusudana Saraswathi agrees with this book means its accepted by Advaitins as authentic.

Comment: Sorry, not here, skeptics stack exchange, if you need further answers. @MrGreenGold

Comment: @user23407 that would be off topic there. This is Hindu related question. Nothing to do with scepticism much.

Comment: Perfectly on topic if you frame it as an authorship issue and the rest as sub questions. However, your choice. @MrGreenGold

Comment: You can take a look at some questions there. @MrGreenGold

Comment: @user23407 you have to tag me at the the beginning for me to get notification. Any way thanks for the suggestion I'll ask there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sarva-Siddhānta-Saṅgrahaḥ (also known as Sarva-darsana-siddhanta Sangrah) is definitely a work of Adi Shankara. In fact, Adi Shankara followed up this work with the  [Sarva Vedānta Siddhānta Sāra Saṅgraha](https://archive.org/details/SarvaVedantaSiddhantaSaraSangraha/page/n11/mode/2up), which is the collection of all vedanta works. Further, this was the inspiration of Swami Madhavacharya Vidyaranya of the Sringeri pontiff in 1331 AD to compile all siddhantas together in his work, [Sarva-darsana Sangraha](https://archive.org/details/Sarva-Darsana-Samgraha.by.Madhavacharya-Vidyaranya.tr.by.E.B.Cowell). In fact, he quotes from this book indirectly using the same sutras for certain philosophies. The book is also quoted by Madhusudana Saraswati. Therefore, one can conclude this is a work of Adi Shankaracharya.

Now, coming to your next question, Veda Vyasa Siddhanta is different from Vedanta Siddhanta. The veda vyasa siddhanta discussed in this work is actually similar to the Samkhya philosophy. This philosophy is given by Vyasa in the Mahabharata and has nothing to do the philosophy of the vedanta sutras by badarayana.

THE SYSTEM OF VEDAVYASA.

> 1. Now, the essence of the Vedas, which has been given out by Vyasa in the Mahabharata so as to be in agreement with all the Sastras, is in
>    fact derived from the system of the Sahkhyas by the believers in the
>    Vedas,
> 2. This world is made up of two things, namely, the Purusa and the prakrti, The higher (of these two), abiding in the 'city' made up of
>    the rudimentary elemental principles, is held to be the purusa.

One has to note that Shankara differentiates between the works of Vyasa in Mahabharata from the work in vedanta sutras. Bādarāyana was the Guru (teacher) of Jaimini and is the composer of the vedanta sutras. Some say he is different from Vyasa of Mahabharata. But tradition holds they are the same. Leaving that aside, Shankara differentiates between the vyasa kara mata and bhasya kara mata. Therefore, an explanation is required as why Shankara differentiates between the two philosophies. Madhusudana saraswati explains why in great detail but suffice it to say this is given in some detail **in pages xv-xviii of the book you reference**.

Comment: Wait wait this is so confusing, so Badarayana and Veda Vyas are different people?? Also didn't Vedas Vyasa himself believe in this philosophy of Vesa Vyasa Siddhanta. In the guruparampara of Advaita there is Vyasa, so Shankaracharya would agree with Veda Vyasa. So Veda Vyasa doesnt believe in philosophy which is named after him??

Comment: So basically Veda Vyasa does not believe in Veda Vyasa Siddhanta??

Comment: but don't we Advaitins have Veda Vyasa in our Guru parampara?

Comment: @Mr Green Gold sir, I have added a small paragraph at the end. Shankara has differentiated between the philosophy presented in Mahabharata and vedanta sutras. Whether both were from the same vyasa, we don't know. But we certainly follow vyasa in our guru parampara.